# E-bike battery charger making horrible noises, only works certain outlets?

Tags: electric-bike, battery, charging

I had posted on endless sphere but since then I have possibly made a little discovery.

Tldr; I have a fresh 48v battery and charger around less than 3 months old. Very intermittently when trying to charge the battery the charger will power up, the fan spins up and then it starts to make a nasty buzzing / whirring sound. Its pretty loud normally but this is something else.

My discovery since the last post is that I no longer believe this is a broken fan issue, as I know that can make a lot of noise. I will not dismiss the possibility by any means though. Main reason for believing this is that when I charge at home it boots up fine and lightly whirrs. But more often than not I have noticed when I am charging in my place of work, this weird sound starts like clockwork almost as soon as I turn it on.

I can be entirely sure of this but id say i cant remember it once doing it at home, but its happened around 10 times now in work. Sometimes it can charge fine even on the supply, it is kind of odd.

I have attached a picture of the charger and a video sample of the noise it makes.

It is a generic style chinese brand charger so criticise if you wish but this is brand new, CE and RoHS tested.

Any help or SUGGESTIONS FOR A NEW CHARGER using the bespoke connector it has would be GREATLY appreciated.

The charger is a generic-style C300 model battery charger, similar to the one shown below:
[image]

[Charger noise video] https://streamable.com/1kmpr

[3 Pin DIN style connector, not XLR]
[image]

Comment: 3 months, this is rather a warranty issue. Consult your dealer ASAP.

Comment: If all else fails splice the old connector onto the new cable.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the clicking in that video from the charger itself or from you turning it on and off? Assuming the former, something is tripping and restarting.  Do other devices work the same on both outlets? If you can find an incandescent lamp is it the same brightness on both?

Comment: Oh, and stupid question:  Did  you check around the fan to see if a piece of trash may have fallen in there?

Comment: @ChrisH Yes the clicking is me, I'm turning it off because I don't like to leave it in that state too long, seems damaging perhaps but maybe not.

Comment: @Carel True, I will tonight, Just a pain with them being so far away, ordered the thing direct so getting stuff from China is silly on postage times

Comment: @DanielRHicks Tried and true method ofc, If all else fails ill take some readings if I can and get a satiator charger or something nice and splice the connector. Also any ideas what this connector is people? Reention dorado plus spec here says "PLA0271 3 pin charging port" but I cant find any reference. http://www.reention.com/product/detail/66

Comment: @DanielRHicks nvm that is a product code, I am looking into the spec now

Comment: If it works fine at home and makes noise at work it's also possible there's EM noise in the power system at your work, a ground leakage or something.

Comment: If the OP is confident with a multimeter it wouldn't be too hard to measure the output. Most chargers for 48V will output more than 48V. I've had noisy chargers in the past, it's possible your home is working on 50hz and your office is 60hz.

Comment: @Dan K Sure no problem, not sure how it works with the signal wire, whether it will show 48 or any voltage unless the signal receives +ve, also I considered that too as we have some archaic machines that may run on 60hz, But the charger seems to be allowable in both ranges and at 120 / 240. I tried a socket in another part of the building and it seemed fine butI checked on it regularly.  The affected sockets seem to be the mass of duplicated inline sockets along the walls near computers etc on the periphery of the building. Seems to be the answer so I will test stuff and close this. Thanks all

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this ?  What happened in the end ?

Answer (score 4):

Even though the **design** may be CE compliant, the unfortunate reality is that cheap manufacturers will still leave out "unnecessary" circuit components or replace them with fake ones when actually building it.  (RoHS just means it's free of lead and mercury etc etc, nothing to do with quality or usability of the electrical design.)

The components that are supposed to filter and reject electromagnetic noise are common victims since they're both expensive and it "normally" works just fine without them.

So if it works fine at home but makes weird noises at work, it seems more likely there's a failing connection in the electrical power system at your work putting a lot of noise on the line, rather than a problem with your charger.  (Other than potentially failing to reject an amount of noise that other DC supplies in the building seem to be handling, whether due to a lazy design or corners being cut in assembly.)

Comment: correct yes a lot of manufcaturers are cheap with their CE compliance and find as many ways to cut costs asides the main components, really disappointing. Frey ebike are fairly reputable company but this charger is off brand generic so wouldnt surprise me.

Comment: @affe would there be a way to add the 'noise filtering' in between the outlet at his place of work and the charger itself?(to be able to keep using the existing charger?)

Comment: *If* that is the root problem it's a potential fire hazard in the building and they should be doing something about it, not mitigating it on the decide side!  Didn't want to get into all that not knowing what OP's location is and it getting pretty far off topic.  (But yes there are some types of devices you can find with a google for 'AC Line Filter' or 'Power Line Filter' if the problem is in some way 'legitimate' (like the panel is shared with a machine shop or something...I dunno...?) and not an arcing fault or ground leak.)

Comment: Hi, I will be mentioning these comments to some engineers in our building thanks to you, just in case of course. We are based in quite a large 4 floor building with duplicated sockets almost every few metres in some places along these conduits that run the length of the walls. Lots of pc equipment etc so lots of separate lines, can see where they might run into interference problems but I don't know a whole lot, will pass the comments on thanks to you guys x-) you learn something new everyday, its ‘essentially’ the building and not the charger  Although the manufacturers have cheaped out..

Answer (score 1):

That sounds just like a normal high speed fan in a charger to me.  My charger has one and sounds like that when charging, stops when battery is charged even when still connected.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. Please only use the "answer" button to answer the OP's question. Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment everywhere](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the site.

Comment: Welcome to the site - OP confirmed in comments that the wall socket used at work was "strange" and the charger worked fine on other sockets.   This noise was definitely not normal.

Answer (score 1):

**It may be miswired plug.**

If the plug of the charger contains three terminals, it may be incorrectly wired, by swapping ground and neutral. This is a dangerous configuration to use that also may or may not work, depending on what the installation does with the ground wire. Ground and neutral wires [should not actually be connected](https://www.circuitsgallery.com/what-happens-if-you-connect-neutral-to-ground/) right at the socket or nearby, but they are [often connected](https://ep2000.com/understanding-neutral-ground-grounding-bonding/?v=e75edac1b83f) at the final step-down transformer of the supply. Some particular socket may not have ground connected at all so this explains why the wrongly wired plug works on some sockets and not others.

It may be the case if the plug has been manually replaced, cutting away a plug from one country and screwing on a different plug for another.

If the power cable of the charger can be disconnected from the charger and there is a replacement at hand, I would suggest to try with another cable.

While in the simplest case ground and neutral are simply connected together at the system neutral point, it may be more complex safety devices installed there that could interfere with the voltage converter of the battery charger, causing it overheat, produce the excess noise or simply prevent from working.

Comment: The plug works in one location but not in another. It is, however, possible that the _socket_ was miswired at one or the other location. You can get socket testers to tell you if the mains / neutral / ground were miswired.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the different outlets are just a red herring. The loud unhealthy noise that broken fans make is actually coming from the fan's bearings. In effect, that fan's axis is dancing around withing the play of the bearing, creating the gruesome noise, producing heat, and damaging the bearing further.

Now, bearings are frequently lubricated, and the viscosity of the lubricant depends on environmental factors. Most notorious is the temperature of the bearing itself, but also humidity may play a part.

When you use your charger at work, the charger is likely at quite a different temperature (for instance by being transported on the bike) than when you charge your battery at home, and that may trip the bearing into dancing.